# Export data from jqxgrid

Tags: jqxgrid

I want to export all data in my jqxgrid into json and send it to another page via AJAX.
My problem is when I click export button, the data in the grid and data before export was not the same. It change float number to Interger. Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
$('#export_bt').on('click', function(){
  var row = $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('exportdata', 'json');
  $('#debug').html(row);
  console.log(row);
});

var tableDatas = [
  {"timestamp":"06:00:00","A":99.49,"B":337.77,"C":155.98},
  {"timestamp":"07:00:00","A":455.67,"B":474.1,"C":751.68},
  {"timestamp":"08:00:00","A":1071.02,"B":598.14,"C":890.47}
];

var tableDatafields = [
  {"name":"timestamp","type":"string"},
  {"name":"A","type":"number"},
  {"name":"B","type":"number"},
  {"name":"C","type":"number"}
];

var tableColumns = [
  {"text":"Times","datafield":"timestamp","editable":"false","align":"center","cellsalign":"center","width":150},
  {"text":"A","datafield":"A","editable":"false","align":"center"},
  {"text":"B","datafield":"B","editable":"false","align":"center"},
  {"text":"C","datafield":"C","editable":"false","align":"center"}
];

function setTableData(table_data,table_column,table_datafields)
{
  sourceTable.localdata = table_data;
  sourceTable.datafields = table_datafields;
  dataAdapterTable = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(sourceTable);
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({columns:table_column});
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('updatebounddata');
  $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('sortby', 'timestamp', 'asc');
  $("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid('autoresizecolumns');

  for(var i=0;i<table_column.length;i++){
    $('#jqxgrid').jqxGrid('setcolumnproperty',table_column[i].datafield,'cellsrenderer',cellsrenderer);
  }
}

var cellsrenderer = function (row, columnfield, value, defaulthtml, columnproperties) {
  if (value||value===0) {
    return value;
  }
  else {
    return '-';
  }
};

var sourceTable ={ localdata: '', datatype: 'array'};

var dataAdapterTable = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(sourceTable);
dataAdapterTable.dataBind();

$("#jqxgrid").jqxGrid({
  width: '500',
  autoheight:true,
  source: dataAdapterTable,
  sortable: true,
  columnsresize: false,
  selectionmode: 'none',
  columns: [{ text: '', datafield: 'timestamp', width:'100%' , editable: false, align:'center'}]
});

setTableData(tableDatas,tableColumns,tableDatafields);
```

Html:

```
<div id="jqxgrid"></div>
<button id="export_bt">Export</button>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jedipalm/jHE7k/1/

Comment: I don't see the problem. Your jsFiddle seems to return floats, not integer. May be que jqWidgets teams fix the problem in the last release?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the data type in your source object as below.

```
datafields: [{ "name": "timestamp", "type": "number" }]
```

And also I suggest you to apply cellsformat in your column definition.

```
{ text: 'timestamp', datafield: 'timestamp', cellsalign: 'right', cellsformat: 'd' }
```

The possible formats can be seen [here](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-documentation/documentation/jqxgrid/jquery-grid-cellsformatting.htm).

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You can export data in very fast way just like it is id jqxGrid with

```
var rows = $("#jqxGrid").jqxGrid("getrows");
```

It will be json array.